# Should we have separate bowls for the cat?

Tags: cats, feeding, public-health

My roommate started using my bowls to feed their cat wet food. Are there any risks to anyone eating from the same bowls if the cat stays indoors?

Comment: @trond I see no reason why veterinary public health questions of this kind should not be asked here

Comment: @HarryV. I agree with you.  Just because a question is ontopic for another site, doesn't mean it's not ontopic for here. https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/473/the-health-tag-and-health-of-humans I think the creation of a separate tag for humans is a good idea.  Please note - I asked that original meta question.

Answer (score 2):

There is a risk, but it is impossible to say how high that risk is as there are (to my knowledge) no studies assessing the risk of humans and cats eating from the same bowls.

Cats have mouths full of bacteria, some of which – *Pasteurella*, *Salmonella*, *Bartonella*, etc. – can cause severe disease in humans. If the cat somehow fecally contaminates its food dish, then there could be a host of other bacterial (e.g. *E. coli*) and protozoal (e.g. *Giardia)* organisms present that can be transmitted to humans through the oral route.

My assumption is that the bowls are washed appropriately in hot water between uses. A dishwasher is sufficient to make sure most bacteria, protozoa and viruses are killed.

The likelihood of transmitting these diseases from cat to humans with washed bowls is probably very low, but it is an unnecessary risk to take. Set aside a couple of dishes for the cat's own use, then you don't have to worry about this risk at all.

Comment: Harry you should let people know you're a vet. It adds more authority to your posts.